# Is there a vsVim User Guide?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vsvim

I've just recently downloaded vsVim to use it with Visual Studio 2010 and join the **Vi** way.  But I haven't been able to find information regarding the specific vsVim documentation.

I know how to use Vim (basic use, nothing even intermediate) but I would like to know if there is something that is still missing from the vsVim implementation, or some special feature.

So could anyone point me to a good resource **about vsVim**?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't believe there is any such documentation -- I personally just kind of go by feel, sometimes things that work in normal Vim don't work the same in VsVim (i.e. `c3<space>`, which I had to replace with `c3l`).  [JaredPar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) is the author of the library and a regular here, so maybe he'll drop by and prove me wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Jared has said that the [git issue list](http://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues) is the main place he tracks feature requests and issues - so having a look at requests should give you an idea of what notable features are missing.

Comment: The thing is that I'm new to the whole Vim thing... so I don't know what is there and what is missing... I want to learn how to use Vim, but right now I can't tell if something is not working because I'm doing it wrong or because it hasn't been implemented yet

Comment: Use regular old Vim as well as VS. Typing emails, commit notes, todo lists, coding html - use vim to do all of this. That's the only way to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Wiki](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki), which explains things such as (intended) [nonstandard behavior](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki). Also, watching the GitHub repository is a good way to learn both what is and isn't implemented in VsVim and also to learn Vim features that you didn't know about. I've certainly learned a number of things about Vim from feature requests that are posted there, etc.

There are many things missing from the VsVim implementation, and there always will be. There are just certain areas of Visual Studio that you can't accurately layer Vim on top of (for example, the mismatch between the way Visual Studio handles documents, windows and tabs and the way that Vim handles buffers, windows and tabs). However, more and more is supported continuously, and you can always submit a pull request. Jared is very friendly and good to work with. I started using VsVim a year and a half ago and already much more is supported then when I started using it.

If you are wondering whether you are doing somethign wrong or whether it just isn't implemented in VsVim, a good thing to do is to pop open Vim and use its `:help` feature to find out. You can always submit an issue on GitHub, or if you really want to learn Vim in a detailed way, you could work on implementing a feature.

Finally, the documentation is incomplete, but since it is a wiki, you are welcome to contribute to it as you learn.